# Missing disk space after boot camp assistant failure

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, startup

I was trying to use Boot Camp Assistant to create a Windows 10 partition, but it got stuck at partitioning. After about a hour, I gave up and force quit the Assistant, and discovered that 3 terabytes of disk space was missing (the amount I was partitioning for windows).

I tried to use Disk Utility to remove the partition, but it doesn't even show up on Disk Utility!

These are the results from `diskutil cs list` and `diskutil list`

`diskutil cs list`

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 26E3C087-C1FF-46F8-9DD7-2CEE7F9592BB
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         3120722075648 B (3.1 TB)
    Free Space:   2305866842112 B (2.3 TB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 2963E8F0-102D-429A-9CAD-9D87D58E4924
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 2D8A34CE-EEC4-4692-AD03-45C554D32CFC
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     2999733223424 B (3.0 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 901E66C6-A3BD-4680-8B65-729A56439096
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume BBE9C3EC-912C-41CC-989D-863C17F82ADD
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          808999976960 B (809.0 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

`diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            3.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +809.0 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2, disk0s2
                                 BBE9C3EC-912C-41CC-989D-863C17F82ADD
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +69.2 MB    disk3
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Paragon Hard Disk Ma... 69.2 MB    disk3s2
```

These are screen shots of the Disk Utility program

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by running `diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk0` on recovery mode.